# Why do all the lists in my array change when I append a new list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm coding with python 3.6 and am working on a Genetic Algorithm. When generating a new population, when I append the new values to the array all the values in the array are changed to the new value. Is there something wrong with my functions?

Code:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import numpy as np
import random
import time

def mutate(parent):
    x = random.randint(0,len(parent)-1)
    parent[x] = random.randint(0,9)
    print(parent)
    return parent

def gen(cur_gen, pop_size, fittest):
    if cur_gen == 1:
        population = []
        for _ in range(pop_size):
            add_to = []
            for _ in range(6):
                add_to.append(random.randint(0,9))
            population.append(add_to)
        return population
    else:
        population = []
        for _ in range(pop_size):
            print('\n')
            population.append(mutate(fittest))
            print(population)
        return population

def get_fittest(population):
    fitness = []
    for x in population:
        fitness.append(fuzz.ratio(x, [9,9,9,9,9,9]))
    fittest = fitness.index(max(fitness))
    fittest_fitness = fitness[fittest]
    fittest = population[fittest]
    return fittest, fittest_fitness

done = False
generation = 1
population = gen(generation, 10, [0,0,0,0,0,0])
print(population)

while not done:
    generation += 1
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('Current Generation: ',generation)
    print('Fittest: ',get_fittest(population))
    if get_fittest(population)[1] == 100:
        done = True
    population = gen(generation, 10, get_fittest(population)[0])
print('Population: ',population)
```

Output:

```
Fittest:  ([7, 4, 2, 7, 8, 9], 72)


[3, 4, 2, 7, 8, 9]
[[3, 4, 2, 7, 8, 9]]


[3, 4, 2, 7, 5, 9]
[[3, 4, 2, 7, 5, 9], [3, 4, 2, 7, 5, 9]]


[3, 4, 2, 7, 4, 9]
[[3, 4, 2, 7, 4, 9], [3, 4, 2, 7, 4, 9], [3, 4, 2, 7, 4, 9]]


[3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 9]
[[3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 9], [3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 9], [3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 9], [3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 9]]


[3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 2]
[[3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 2], [3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 2], [3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 2], [3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 2], [3, 1, 2, 7, 4, 2]]


[3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2]
[[3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2]]


[3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2]
[[3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2]]


[3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5]
[[3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5]]


[3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3]
[[3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3]]
```

Comment: Could you update your question with the code and expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: Why does your output not contain `Current Generation` or `Population`, and contain `Fittest` only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep passing `fittest`, a reference to the same list, to `mutate`, which modifies the list in-place, and append it to `population`, so changes to the list in the next iteration are reflected across all the references to `fittest` in the `population` list.

You should pass a copy of the `fittest` list to `mutate` instead:

```
population.append(mutate(fittest[:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's right there in the name:

```
def mutate(parent):
    x = random.randint(0,len(parent)-1)
    parent[x] = random.randint(0,9)
    print(parent)
    return parent
```

`mutate` isn't making a new `list`, it's modifying the existing `list` in place and returning a reference to the same `list` it was passed. `population.append(mutate(fittest))` is happily storing aliases to `fittest` over and over, and since `fittest` is never replaced, it just keeps getting mutated and new aliases to it stored.

If the goal is to store a snapshot of the `list` at a given stage each time, copy it, changing:

```
population.append(mutate(fittest))
```

to:

```
population.append(mutate(fittest)[:])
```

where a complete slice of the `list` makes a shallow copy. `population.append(mutate(fittest).copy())` would also work on modern Python, as would `import copy`, then doing `population.append(copy.copy(mutate(fittest)))` or (if the contents might themselves be mutable, though they aren't in this case) `population.append(copy.deepcopy(mutate(fittest)))`.

Note that as a rule, Python functions aren't really supposed to both mutate *and* return the mutated value, as it leads to confusion like this.

Pythonic code intended to mutate in place returns `None` (implicitly usually, by not returning at all), so the code you'd use would actually be:

```
def mutate(parent):
    x = random.randint(0,len(parent)-1)
    parent[x] = random.randint(0,9)
    print(parent)
```

and used with:

```
        mutate(fittest)  # Mutate fittest in place
        population.append(fittest[:])  # Append copy of most recently updated fittest
```